# Обработка ошибки при обращению к серверу

Tags: python, requests

Использую библиотеку `requests` для обращения к серверу и присваиваю переменной определенный скачанный элемент со страницы.

```
r = requests.get('http://...')
```

Проблема в том, что сервер нестабилен, и в определенный момент он может быть выключен, из-за чего программа падает. Моей задачей является добавить обработку ошибки, при которой сервер не дает ответа. Например, выражаясь более простым языком - вывести в консоль "Ошибка" если ответа от сервера не последовало, либо просто продолжить исполнение программы в случае ответа сервера.

Comment: а просто `try` `except` ?

Comment: [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, как уже подсказали, изучите в принципе [тему ошибок и исключений в Питоне](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). Затем можно смотреть конкретные исключения, специфические для модуля `requests`. Обрабатывать их можно например так:

```py
try:
    r = requests.get(url, params={'s': thing})
    # Обработать ответ
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    # Вероятно сервер болеет, можно попробовать ретрай через N секунд
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    # Вероятно некорректный URL
except requests.ConnectionError:
    # Нет соединения с сервером
```

Полезные материалы:

- [enSO: Correct way to try/except using Python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16511337/5308802)
- [enSO: Python requests exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9054820/5308802)
- [requests.readthedocs.io: Exceptions](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/) – здесь полный список исключений библиотеки `requests`.

Для построения более грамотной обработки подобных ситуаций, можно использовать специальные модули вроде [`retry`](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) [`retrying`](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/), которые позволяют в декларативном виде через декораторы задавать правила обработки исключений – повторения запросов, их количество, интервалы между повторами и т.п.